# Assign value to dropdownlist items & display in label

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, label

I have a dropdown list, what I would like to do is assign values to the items in the drop down list and then display these values in a label depending on which item is selected..

Here is what I have already:

```
           <tr>
           <td width="343">Package*</td>

    <td colspan="4">

<select class="purple" name="package">
    <option value="standard">Standard - &euro;55 Monthly</option>
    <option value="standardAnn">Standard - &euro;49 Monthly</option>            
    <option value="premium">Premium - &euro;99 Monthly</option>
    <option value="premiumAnn" selected="selected">Premium - &euro;89 Monthly</option>            
    <option value="platinum">Platinum - &euro;149 Monthly</option>
    <option value="platinumAnn">Platinum - &euro;134 Monthly</option>            
</select>
</td>
<tr>

<td width="343">
  <p style="font-size:14px;">We bill quarterly/annually in advance</p>
  <p style="font-size:14px;">See <a href="#dialog" name="modal">Pricing</a> for more details
  </p></td>

    <td colspan="4"><label id="total" name="total">Total Cost:</label></td>
```

The jQuery code I currently have changes the value of the label to the ACTUAL contents of the drop down list, however I want to assign the following values to the contents of the dropdownlist:

Standard = "€165 Quarterly"
StandardAnn = "€588 Annually"
Premium = "€297 Quarterly"
PremiumAnn = "€1068 Annually"
Platinum = "€447 Quarterly"
PlatinumAnn = "€1608 Annually"

This is so that when the user selects a certain package, the total price will be displayed to them as they either pay quarterly in advance, or annually in advance. Trying to prevent a shock when they get to the payment page!
Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('select[name=package]').change(
      function(){
        var newText = $('option:selected',this).text();
        $('#total').text('Total price: ' + newText);
      }
      );
  } );
```

I'm having a bit of trouble adapting the code as I'm new to jQuery and I'm under pressure to have this done. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Are you able to adapt the html structure at all? Or is the absolutely-final version that has to be lived with?

Comment: originally I was going to suggest using html5's custom data attributes, but then I realised that would just complicate things unnecessarily. So I used some (simple) regex instead. It took me a while to remember how to use JavaScript's `match()` though (mainly because I despise regex, and generally forget how it works if I don't use it for more than half an hour...) =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an array of the text you want to display

```
var AnnualCosts = [];
AnnualCosts['standard'] = "€165 Quarterly";
AnnualCosts['standardAnn'] = "€588 Annually";
...


$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('select[name=package]').change(
      function(){
        var newText = AnnualCosts[$('option:selected',this).val()];
        $('#total').text('Total price: ' + newText);
      }
      );
  }
```

not very best practice but your whole code isnt. this is quick and dirty. not so maintainable.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Just need something up today so quick and dirty is fine for now. When I try this solution I get undefined in the label. Any ideas?

Comment: try alert(AnnualCosts['standard']) to see if the array is fine, also try alert($('option:selected',this).val()) to see if the key is working. one of them is not correct :)

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I forgot to change .text() to .val() which was why it was giving undefined. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while longer than I expected, and involves no re-writing of your html (that I can remember doing, anyway), but the following does work:

#### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('select[name=package]').change(        
      function(){
          var monthly = $('input:checked[name=billPeriod]').val();
    var price = $(':selected',this).text();
    var price = price.match('[0-9]{2,3}');

  if (monthly == 0) {
    var recurrence = 'quarterly';
    var cost = price * 4;
  }
  else if (monthly == 1) {
    var recurrence = 'annually';
    var cost = price * 12;
  }

    $('#total').text('Total price ('+recurrence+'): €' + cost);
      }
      );
  }
  );
```

#### html:

```
  <form id="packageChoices" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="billPeriod">Bill:</label>
      <input type="radio" name="billPeriod" value="0" />Quarterly
      <input type="radio" name="billPeriod" value="1" checked />Annually
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <select class="purple" name="package">
        <option value="standard">Standard - &euro;55 Monthly</option>
        <option value="standardAnn">Standard - &euro;49 Monthly</option> 
        <option value="premium">Premium - &euro;99 Monthly</option>
        <option value="premiumAnn" selected="selected">Premium - &euro;89 Monthly</option>
        <option value="platinum">Platinum - &euro;149 Monthly</option>
        <option value="platinumAnn">Platinum - &euro;134 Monthly</option>            
</select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label id="total">Total Price: </label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Live demo: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/awuqo4/)

I realise that you've already accepted an answer, but it seemed a waste to throw away the last half hour of trying to remember how simple regex works... =)

Comment: Sorry David, I've marked it one up if that's any consolation. Thanks for your original help.

Comment: No worries at all, I've enjoyed the challenge =) Sorry for being so slow on the up-take...and hey, I posted the answer knowing you'd already accepted another, so no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty regex, based on the value displayed in the select field, should work:

```
var annualCost = 12 * $('option:selected').html().match(/\d+/);
$('#total').html('Total price: &euro;' + annualCost);
```

Again, this isn't the best practice, but I think it will work.  NB that this will break if any other numbers are before the price in the drop down menu options.